# How to provide a searchpath for shared libs in /usr/lib for `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf`-Target?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to crosscompile to target `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`.
In order to do so, i rustup my project with `rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`.

Further, i downloaded the ARM-Toolchain and created a .cargo/config.toml:

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "/path/to/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld"
```

finaly, i try to build my project with

```sh
cargo build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

This fails with

```
note: /path/to/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpv
```

mpv is located at:

```sh
ldconfig -p | grep mpv

libmpv.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmpv.so.1
libmpv.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmpv.so
```

The build for my default-target `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` is successfull.

How to provide a searchpath for shared libs in /usr/lib for `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf`-Target?

Comment: my libmpv is ELF 64-bit LSB and not suitable for a 32bit target. Refer to https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/5856 and https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv.io/blob/master/source/guides/cross-compilation.rst